# jQuery cropper doesn't allow upload an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try using this jQuery cropper http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/#examples , but there isnt any way to upload an image from your pc to cropper it, anyway the plugin page says that i have to upload using HTML5 FileReader object.

I try to do as follows:

**HTML code:**

```
<img id="cropper">
<input id="inputImage" name="image" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(function() {

    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        $("#cropper").attr("src", dataURL);
    };

});
```

Now thatIf you run the code it works perfectly but when i try to modify the plugin src image attribute it doesnt works :(

any ideas? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You should destroy the existed cropper first before you replace the image: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/493#issuecomment-152051663